# C++/Java bindings : In which side should multi-threading be implemented?

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, download, java-native-interface

I am implementing a C++ class called `HttpDataStream` in my library. I have to do the JNI bindings in order to use my library under Android, with the Objective-C bindings for iOS.

I need to create a dedicated `HttpDataStream` class in both Java and Objective-C, but I'm wondering if these classes would actually block the whole application until the download has finished.

For instance, let's call a `read` method from the `HttpDataStream` class on the "Android side" :

```
std::streamsize DataStreamJava::read(double value) {
  jmethodID m = jni->GetMethodID(j_dataStream_class_,
                                 "read", "(D)J");
  jni->CallLongMethod(j_dataStream_global_, m);
  return 0;
}
```

Let's say the `read` method would download the file and return the number of downloaded bytes. I'm currently thinking that, even if I use Threads and Runnables on the "Android side", the C++ library would actually block until the download is finished.

So I'm asking myself the following questions :

- Should multi-threading be implemented both on the C++ and Java side ?
- Should I implement a DataStreamObserver in C++ that will be called once the download has finished ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what do you expect from the multithreading:

**a) pipelining related actions on one side**

If your `read()` on Java side performs several dependend actions such as reading, interpreting or pre-proessing the data, and eventually rendering it, you could consider doing the multithreading on the java side.

But however you do it on that side, your single call to the stream class' `read()` would return only when all the mutlithreaded actions on the java side are completed.  So yes, in this case, the C++ code is stuck, waiting for the return.

**b) doing something unrelated**

So if you want your C++ code to do something else while the data is read, but not related to the aquired data, you should consider doing the multithreading on the C++ side (don't forget to attach the JNI environment to the new threads !).

**c) pipelining related actions on both sides**

But if you have to process some part of the aquired data by Java one the C++ side (for example, starting to display the data),  then you could choose one of the following two approaches:

- multithreading in C++, provided you have a way to concurrently access to the data that is being read in java (e.g.reading small chunks,  or java function giving access to the buffers being filled)
- multithreading in java calling on native C++ functions as callback everytime some partial data is ready: in this case, JNI will take care of running each called-back C++ function in a distinct thread corresponding to the Java thread.

**The obsrever in java or in C++**

It depends on your choice and constraints related to the previous choices.  Without knowing more, it's difficult to give you an objective and useful advice.

Answer (score 1):

If thats a longer download operation, then under Android it is recomended to do it from thread inside (possibly foreground) service. This way system will not kill your app once user hides it. In this scenerio its better to create thread on java side.

In application I work on, I have lots of native code which is executed in its own native threads. This code is doing HTTP communication by calling methods on java class - which wraps various android HTTPClient methods. Those are mostly small amounts of data.

So:

> Should multi-threading be implemented both on the C++ and Java side ?

for small amounts of data I would do threading in C++ code and call java class which wraps HTTPClient or URL. You can use for this pthreads which should work on android and ios with little changes.

For larger amounts of data, at least under android - use java thread in service. This actually makes it hard to code operations like read in c++.

I am not sure about streamed data, which I understand is your case, if you need data immediately - then native threads should be best.